Dominor 400 Stopping when gear is downshifted
I have owned my dominor 400 2 months back and first service is done at 600km approx now at 1800km iam facing this issue when iam downshifting the gears suddenly if iam in 4th any obstacle is present them if i downshift to 2nd or 1st bike is stopping iam unable to understand what is the problem kindly give any suggestions so that i can proceed.
Thank you.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not understanding your issue? Is this something to do with your driving technique or is there something wrong with the bike itself? Could you please edit your question and provide more detail?

You say first service at 600km and now 1800km, is it a new bike which is covered under warranty? As for driving technique (off topic) downshifting the gears when an obstacle forces sudden braking is always a problem with a sequential gearbox. If you are downshifting too soon from 4th to 2nd and 1st that may well cause the bike to stop sharply. Is this your first bike? The downshifting takes practice, and if stopping suddenly it can be easier to declutch and focus on the incident. Then you have to select neutral at a standstill, and you might need to rock the bike a bit fowards and backwards.
